# Docker: What's the difference between --link tag:db and --link tag:mysql

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I've been trying to migrate to docker with MySQL and PHP but am having trouble getting my head around linking containers. I've managed to get `mysql:5.7` working with `wordpress:latest` and `phpmyadmin` to test it by running:

```
docker run --name testdb -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql:5.7

docker run --name testadmin -d --link testdb:db -p8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin

docker run --name testwp -d -p 80:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password --link testdb:mysql wordpress
```

Using `tag:db` where I've used `tag:mysql` and vice versa brings up connection problems. I'm trying to understand the difference and whether using `tag:db` or `tag:mysql` determines the connection type i.e. sockets vs tcp

I've tried searching for documentation on specifics to do with linking but either there isn't much info about the different link types or my googlefu isn't up to snuff.

Im still drilling down through phpmyadmin's source as well as wordpress's source to work out what functions they're using but will take me some time to take it all in. Any info or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you referring to testdb:db?

Comment: Leave the difference apart, you should not be using `--link` in docker anymore as it is deprecated and will removed in upcoming versions

Comment: yes Sergiu when ive tried testdb:mysql on the phpmyadmin link it gives errors aswell as using testdb:db for wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Tarun Lalwani.

Answer (score 0):

MySql container looks correct for me, so keep using:

```
docker run --name testdb -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql:5.7
```

But in phpadmin you have to use name `testdb` in link to MySql, like:

```
docker run --name testadmin -d --link testdb -p8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Here you have clear link from this container to another `testdb`, hence inside phpmyadmin you can refer to MySql container.

For `wordpress` you have to do the same, and link to MySql container's name, like:

```
docker run --name testwp -d -p 80:80 --link testdb wordpress
```

And you don't have to provide MySql root password here, because this password intended for MySql container not for this.

This approach works for me, hope it'll help you!

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, when I leave off the :mysql on the phpmyadmin command it just hangs and resets